# Assign mock server to spring cloud discovery client

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

We currently use spring boot 2.3.4 and feign internally uses ribbon to load balance the servers. In integration tests we used MockWebServer to let ribbon know the mockserver url and port

```
mockServer = new MockWebServer();
mockServer.start();  

List<Server> servers = Arrays.asList(new Server(mockServer.getHostName(), mockServer.getPort()));
when(serverList.getInitialListOfServers()).thenReturn(servers);



@Component
    static class TestConfig implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
            TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(configurableApplicationContext,
                    "account-service.ribbon.listOfServers=" + mockServer.getHostName() + ":" + mockServer.getPort());
        }
    }
```

Now upgrading to spring boot 2.7, Spring Cloud Netflix Ribbon has been deprecated and is not included and Spring Cloud LoadBalancer is the suggested alternative.

So I used `spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.instances.account-service[0].uri=http://account-service.com` in the app properties

Doing same for integration tests with mock server does not work

```
@Component
        static class TestConfig implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
            @Override
            public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
                TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(configurableApplicationContext,
                        "spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.instances.account-service[0].uri=" + mockServer.getHostName() + ":" + mockServer.getPort());
            }
        }
```

I have also tried setting this dymically with but no luck

```
@DynamicPropertySource
    static void dynamicProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.instances.account-service[0].uri", () -> mockServer.getHostName() + ":" + mockServer.getPort());
    }
```